# Is there any hardware solution for IDS?

Tags: ids, snort, router

Are there any products that let you see and set **IDS** [Intrusion detection system] on router or any another hardware that is connected to the router?

All the ones I have found of them are Operating Systems like **security onion**, **alien-vault**, **aanval**. All of them are  Linux distributions.

Is there not any another hardware IDS that I can connect to my router or is the router itself?

I ask that because it's much more easier than installing and operating virtual OS. It will also slow down the computer and the logs can be seen only by typing in the browser 192.168.1.1[for example].

Comment: user53427 - that's 2 edits to try and make this on topic.

Comment: So, you're looking for a IDS appliance? There are as many of those as there are IDS vendors.

Answer (score 4):

Large enterprises typically use NIDS - network intrusion detenction devices ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_intrusion_detection_system ). These are usually on a span port on the switch so they don't impact latency. Alternatively you might go for NIPS - network intrusion prevention which must be inline on the network and therefore is likely to alter performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some appliances that incorporate wireless router + IDS or IPS. For example, check out this [Watchguard access point](https://www.watchguard.com/wgrd-products/secure-wireless/overview).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "hardware solution" that there is some specific chip that implements IDS algorithms (like an encryption chip for ciphering data), I am not aware that this is technically feasible. There is no standard algorithm for performing the intrusion detection, the goals of this task are manifold and so are the solution approaches. If you want to recognize malware, you will do this differently that when you want to detect malicious packets on the network.

Therefore, the best thing available will be an appliance like mentioned in the other post. Beware that IDS is never a "install and forget" method, but it requires maintenance. For example in rule-based IDS, the rules have to be updated to keep up with new threats. IDS using learning algorithms will have to be trained to accomodate new threat scenarios.